# Is it better to hold a repository for every web application (context) or is it better to share a common instance by JNDI or a similar technique

Tags: java, servlets, caching, jndi, repository-pattern

within our company it's kind of standard to create repositories for data which is originally stored in the database as described for example in https://thinkinginobjects.com/2012/08/26/dont-use-dao-use-repository/.

Our web infrastructure consist of a few independent web applications within Tomcat 7 for printing, product description, product order (this is not persisted in the database!), category description etc.
They are all build on Servlet 2 API.

So each instance/implementation of repository holds a specialised kind of data represented by serializable classes and the instances of this serialzable classes are set up/filled by an periodically executed database query (for every resultrow the setters of the fields are called; reminds me of domain oriented entity beans with CMP).
The repositories are initialized on the servlets init sequences (so every servlet keeps it's own set of instances).
Each context has a own connection to the Oracle database (set up by resource description file on deployment).
All the data is read only, we never need to write back to the database.

Because we need some of these data types for more than one web application (context) and some even for more than one servlet within the same web context repositories with an identical data type are instantiated more than once - e.g. four times, twice within the same application.

In the end some of the data is doubled and I'm not sure if this is as clever and efficient as it should be. It should be possible to share the same repository object to more than one application (JNDI?) but at least it must be possible to share it for several servlets within the same application context.
Despite I'm irritated by the idea to use a "self build" repository instead of something like a well tested, open developed cache (ehcache, jcs, ...) because some of these caches also provide options for distributed caches (so it should also work within the same container).
If certain entries are searched the search algorithm iterates over all entries in the repository (s. link above). For every search pattern there are specialised functions which are directly called from within the business logic classes using the "entity beans"; there's no specification object or interface.

In the end the application server as a whole does not perform that well and it uses a hell lot of RAM (at least for approximately 10000 DB entries); this is in my opinion most probably correlated to the use of serializeable XSD-to-JAXB-generated classes.

Additionally every time a application is deployed for tests you have to wait at least two minutes until all entries of the database have been loaded into the repositories - when deploying on live there's a well recognizable out of service phase on context/servlet start up.
I tend to think all of this is closely related to the solutions I described above.

Because I haven't got any experiences in this field and I'm new in the company I don't want to be to obtrusive.

Maybe you can help me to evaluate ideas for a better setup:

Is it for performance and memory better to unify all the repositories into one "repository servlet" and request objects from there via HTTP (don't think so, though it seems quite modular/distributed system friendly) or should I try to go with JNDI (never did that before) and connect to the repository similar to a JDBC database?

Wouldn't it be even more sensible, faster and efficient to at least use only one single connection pool for the whole Tomcat (and reference this connection pool from within the web apps deployment descriptor)? Or might that slow down connections or limit it in any other aspect?
I was told that the cache system (ehcache) didn't work well (at least not with the performance of the self written solution - though: I can't believe that). I imagine the usage of repositories backed by a distributed (as across all contexts) cache used in all web applications should not only reduce memory footprint significantly but should not be significantly slower. - I believe it will be faster and have shorter start up times respectively it shouldn't be needed to redeploy it that often.

I'm very grateful for every tip or hint and your thoughts. Would be marvellous to get a peer review of my ideas based on practical experiences.

So thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it better to hold a repository for every web application (context) or is it better to share a common instance by JDNI or a similar technique

Unless someone proves me otherwise I would say there is no way to do it, in a standard way, meaning as defined in the Servlet Sepc or in the rest of the Java EE spec canon.

There are technical ways to do it which probably depend on a specific application server implementation, but this cannot be "better" in its universal sense.

If you have two applications that operate on the same data, I wonder whether the partitioning of the applications is useful. Maybe all functionality operating on some kind of data needs to be in the same application?

> within our company it's kind of standard to create repositories for data which is originally stored in the database as described for example in https://thinkinginobjects.com/2012/08/26/dont-use-dao-use-repository/.

I looked up Evans in our book shelf. The blog post is quite weird. A repository and a DAO are basically the same thing, it provides CRUD operations for an object or for a tree of objects (Evans says only the the aggregate roots).

> The repositories are initialized on the servlets init sequences (so every servlet keeps it's own set of instances). Each context has a own connection to the Oracle database (set up by resource description file on deployment). [ ... ]
>   In the end the application server as a whole does not perform that well and it uses a hell lot of RAM

When something performs badly its the best to do profiling, e.g. with YourKit or with perf and FlameGraphs if you are on Linux. If your applications need a lot of RAM, analyze the heap e.g. with Eclipse MAT. There is no way somebody can give you a recommendation or hint on a best practice without seeing any line of code.

A general answer would include anyting about performance tuning for Oracle DBs, JDBC, Java Collections and Concurrent Programming, Networking and Operating Systems.

> I was told that the cache system (ehcache) didn't work well (at least not with the performance of the self written solution - though: I can't believe that)

I can. EHCache is between 10-20 times slower then a simple HashMap. See: [cache benchmarks](https://cache2k.org/benchmarks.html). You only need a map, when you do a complete preload and don't have any mutations.

> I imagine the usage of repositories backed by a distributed (as across all contexts) cache used in all web applications should not only reduce memory footprint significantly but should not be significantly slower

Distributed caches need to go over the network and add serialization/deserialization overhead. That's probably another factor 30 slower. When is the distributed cache updated?

> I'm very grateful for every tip or hint and your thoughts.

Wrap up:

1. Do the normal software engineering homework, do profiling and analyzing and spend the effort of tuning at the right places
2. Ask specific questions on one topic on stackoverflow and share your code and performance data. Ask a question about one thing at one time and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
3. You may also come to the conclusion that there is nothing to tune. There are applications out there that need a day to build up an in memory data structure from persistent data. Maybe its just a lot of data? If you do not like the downtime use green blue deployment. Also use smaller data sets for development and testing

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Maybe I don't understand what shared objects/resources means. I assumed the following information provide concepts using the same mechanism which is used for shared database pools to share a common datasource (a repository shouldn't be that different conceptually) not only across multiple servlets of a single application but across serveral apllication contexts:

* https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html
* http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafo.html#bnafp

Comment: You write "Distributed caches need to go over the network and add  serialization/deserialization overhead.". Why can't a cache (this is meant to be a functional description) be shared accross several application contexts within the same web container? 
The repositories we use are multiplying data. So every update (the lifecycle of the repsoitory is "load => sleep n seconds => load => sleep n seconds => ..."; somewhere in between there are requests for different objects in this cache) is performed multiple times, even within the same application.
That seems to be a wasteful architecture?

Comment: "Do the normal software engineering homework, do profiling and analyzing and spend the effort of tuning at the right places."
Of course I am doing that and I will continue. But additionally I try to step back and look at the architecture and concepts as a whole.
My late cs prof once said "You can optimize squeezing the lemon for years but if your customer is up for orange lemonade you should simply rather take an orange."
Before optimizing lines of code I'd like to be sure to use a sensible architecture.
Maybe it is not code related itself but it is related to programming and algorithms.

Comment: "That seems to be a wasteful architecture?" That depends on the overall costs and the overall performance. When you save more costs for the request processing than you invest for the reloading, the outcome is positive. The problem is, when no requests are coming in or less requests, then your application isn't efficient and wastes CPU time for the reload. But that's different forms of "efficiency". The latter one is power consumption the other is peak performance for installed resources.

Comment: From what I see, you have also doubts how to efficiently refresh your cache contents. Looking at the title that's far off the original intent of the question. Please separate all the different aspects into a separate question on stackoverflow, if you like to discuss that further. For me it looks interesting. Don't forget to add hard data (how many requests? how many object? how long takes the reload?, etc.) and some code.

Comment: Well, in the current architecture all these are aspects are somehow intrinsic dependent.

Comment: My idea is to use a cache which can be used as distributed cache (and it should be possible to share the cached data between any application of a app container on the same machine), e.g. ehcache.
The cache shall be primed by a repository app, loading all data types into the cache: After startup each typed repository is feed with all items of the specific data type from the database (query without any where restrictions). Each item will be loaded/put in/to the repository/cache (currently we always exchange the complete repo content).
So the repo provides single item cru(d) methods.

Comment: Each data type specific repository of the repo app shall after the initial load continously perform a low priority request for each item in the repo/cache and (if a difference is found the cached item is updated). That way the data in the cache is continously updated with a steady but low load (not a big bang).
And while the repo app is performing the initial "big bang cache prime" the real webservice may request any item/object from the repository - if it was not loaded yet, it shall transparently be initialised and loaded right at that time (using the exact same method).

Comment: That way the repository and the "real webservice" (i.e. the one which answers web requests from the clients out there) are uncoupled and can be deployed independently. If the webservice is updated (this happens significantly more frequently than a change of the repository itself) it's not necessary to reload/restart the repositories.
While the repositories haven't finished preloading the cache answers can be provided (though the answer will be performed much slower) - currently the webservice can't do anything usefull.
The load of the repository update will be distributed eavenly (no peeks).

Comment: The repository should be easier and not more but a well designed request interface for the cache (providing type specific query methods) on top of the geric cache interface. The initial load of data may not only happen in parallel for the different types but also for chunks of a specific data type (not sure if this is really going to have an significant impact; the only partitionable resultset seems to be the CachedRowSet). And subsequently the most of the time unchanged objects in the database won't be replaced if there is no change - this will skip unneeded updates.

Comment: But I think the webservice will be up much faster (ready to respond), it will perform not distinguishably worse (at least I can't see a point why it should be significantly worse in repsonse time).
And we might use things like the file cache on shut down (though this won't help on automatically generated, started and shutdown containers) to reload the last known cache status within the cache itself which could enhance the startup by a exponential factor.